# C# отправить POST запрос и получить ответ

Tags: c#, post, request

Доброе время суток, я не знаю как отправить ПОСТ запрос, но при этом получить ответ от сервера и вывести на экран (типа MessageBox). Помогите пожалуйста.

---

```
StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder(String.Empty);
Uri st = new Uri("https://www.site.az/");
string reqString = String.Format($"id={min}&XXX={op}&login={login}&mac={mac}");
byte[] requestData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reqString);
CookieContainer cc = new CookieContainer();
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Proxy = null;
request.CookieContainer = cc;
request.Method = "POST";
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
using (System.IO.Stream s = request.GetRequestStream())
    s.Write(requestData, 0, requestData.Length);
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
```

Comment: Вот же ваш ответ `using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())` его и читайте.

Comment: Уважаемый ответ выводиться на странице, ( я так понял нужно будет отправить запрос а потом пропарсить страницу найти тег со значение и вывести это значение ... я верно мыслю?

Comment: Смотрите, веб сервер работает по принципу запрос-ответ. Браузер выступает в роли клиента - он отсылает запрос, получает ответ и показывает этот ответ на страничке. Но браузер это такая же программа, как и любая другая программа. То есть вы можете написать свою программу, которая будет отправлять запрос на веб сервер, получать ответ в виде текста странички и делать с этим текстом всё, что вздумается. Например, распарсить этот текст с помощью [html agility pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/), вытащить нужную информацию и показать на вашей форме.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `StreamReader`:

```
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
MessageBox.Show(new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd());
```